# Two problems with a batch to recursively list pathfilename with datetime and size

Tags: batch-file

This batch code:

```
    :: File name: jjlist.bat  (normally, must be in system path)
    ::
    :: Purpose:
    :: batch that lists date/time, justified size and full path and file name.
    :: that goes to the screen or into a named file in current directory (folder)
    ::
    :: To use, at the command line type:
    :: jjlist *.* [or *.jpg etc]
    ::  to direct output to screen.
    :: or
    :: jjlist *.* outfilename.txt
    ::
    :: author: eliasrk(at)gmail.com
    ::
    @echo off
    set outfile=%2
    if "%1x"=="x" goto :end
    if NOT "%2x"=="x" goto :out2file
    :
    :out2screen
    for /r %%I in (%1) do if NOT "%%~tI" == "" call :loop4screen "%%~tI" "%%~zI" "%%I"
    goto :end
    :
    :loop4screen
    set Sz=              %~2
    echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% %~3
    goto :end
    :
    :out2file
    for /r %%I in (%1) do if NOT "%%~tI" == "" call :loop4fileOut "%%~tI" "%%~zI" "%%~xI" "%%I"
    goto :end
    :
    :loop4fileOut
    set Sz=              %~2
    set Ex=%~3        x
    :echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% %Ex:~0,8% %~4 >> %outfile%
    echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% %~4 >> %outfile%
    goto :end
    :
    :end
```

provided that these registry keys are set:

```
[various] "\Control Panel\International"  "iTime"="1"
[various] "\Control Panel\International"  "iTLZero"="1"
[various] "\Control Panel\International"  "sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"
[various] "\Control Panel\International"  "sShortDate"="yyyy-MM-dd"
```

produces a date string sortable listing of this form:

```
2013-04-16 13:35       1293  D:\Documents\T_Args\Drafts\2013_04_15\1st_circle_claim.txt
2013-04-16 11:51       2110  D:\Documents\T_Args\Drafts\2013_04_15\sources_01.txt
2012-10-08 10:45      13599  D:\Documents\T_Args\images_temp\taut_faq_working\new_tautology.txt
2013-02-05 12:54       8829  D:\Documents\T_Args\Popper\Objective_Knowledge\pages.txt
2013-02-05 11:36       8835  D:\Documents\T_Args\Popper\Objective_Knowledge\pages_org.txt
```

Since writing this batch I have discovered two problems which I would like to
know how to correct:

1) When there is an "&" in a filename an error message is generated indicating
that the string following the & was treated as a "command".  I would like such
filenames to be treated normally.

2) If I am in the dir structure to be listed the output of say "jjlist *.doc" is
fine, however if I provide a fully qualified path as in "jjlist
d:\documents*.doc" there is no output.  Can this be fixed?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

### nice & easy

To protect the `&` from parsing, you can enclose it in double quotes **or** use `delayed expansion`. Example:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "fname=nice & easy.txt"
echo %fname%                        &rem error message
echo "%fname%"                      &rem output with quotes
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion     
echo !fname!                        &rem output without quotes
```

## for /r

The `for /r` loop gets its start folder for the recursive search as **parameter**, this **works**:

```
for /r "d:\documents" %%I in (*.doc) do echo %%I
```

but this **doesn't work**:

```
for /r %%I in (d:\documents\*.doc) do echo %%I
```

If you need a path as recursive search pattern, **use this**:

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d /s "d:\documents\*.doc"') do echo %%I
```

Comment: changing from: 
echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% %~4 >> %outfile% 
to 
echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% "%~4" >> %outfile% 
 
and from: 
echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% %~3 
to: 
echo %~1 %Sz:~-10% "%~3" 
 
solves my "&" problem in the pathfilename (which is my biggest problem), but adds quote marks around the output pathfilename, which I am happy to live with. 
 
Using: 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
has no useful effect that I can determine. 
 
I will work on variations of: 
"for /r "d:\documents" %%I in (*.doc) do echo %%I" 
 
May not be back for 2 or 3 weeks 
 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is slow but it will work with any regional settings.  It requires XP pro and above.

Any & characters in filenames are handled ok, but % and ^ in the path\filename will cause issues.

A path\filespec on the command line can be used as well as a logfile name.

```
:: Syntax: mybatchfile [d:\path\[filespec]] [[d:\path\]logfile.txt]
:: date time size filename
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%~1" /b /s /a-d') do call :next "%%a" "%~2"
if "%~2"=="" pause
goto :EOF

:next
set "file=%~1"
set "file=%file:\=\\%"
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file%" get lastmodified,size|find ".">file.tmp
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file.tmp) do set size=%%a&set dt=%%b
set dt=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2% %dt:~8,2%:%dt:~10,2%
set size=                                 %size%
set size=%size:~-18%
for %%a in ("%dt% %size% %~1") do echo %%~a
if not "%~2"=="" for %%a in ("%dt% %size% %~1") do >>"%~2" echo %%~a
del file.tmp
```